# Prolog: Reading input with spaces causes an error

Tags: prolog

this is my program

```
tran('father','otosan').
tran('father','chichiwe').
tran('mother','okasan').
tran('mother','hahawe').
tran('hi','ohayo').
tran('good night','oyasemi').
tran('good bye','sayonara').
tran('do your best','gambaru').
tran('please','onegai').
tran('sorry','gomen').
tran('thank you','aregatto').
tran('cute','kawaii').
eng:- nl,write('enter a word in english: '),read(X),jap(X).
jap(X):- tran(X,Y),write('the word in japanese is '),write(Y),nl,fail.
jap(Z).
:-eng.
```

I got an error in the words with spaces

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What flavor of prolog, and what is the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that when inputting words with spaces, you need to surround them with single quotes:

```
?- ['trans.pl'].
% trans.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 5,432 bytes
true.

?- eng.

enter a word in english: hi.
the word in japanese is ohayo
false.

?- eng.

enter a word in english: 'good bye'.
the word in japanese is sayonara
false.
```

The reason this is happening is that when you enter `hi`, Prolog is unifying it to `jap(hi).` which resolves to `ohayo`. When you enter `good bye`, Prolog unifies it to `jap(good bye)`, which will give you an error (Operator Expected). This is why you need to quote your input as `'good bye'`. Prolog will then unify it to `jap('good bye')`, which gives you what you want.